# Get source file name from an xmlNode?

Tags: c, libxml2

In libxml2, I can easily find the source line that an `xmlNode` came from (`xmlNode::line`), but I can't see how to find the name of the file that it came from.  This is especially useful when the loaded document contains XInclude directives.  While I can think of manual ways of handling this (look for `xml:base` attribute above the given node; manually store the file name and use that if `xml:base` is not set), I'd rather use something built into libxml2.

Is there a function for retrieving the file name from which any given `xmlNode` object was loaded?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/xinclude/#base

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't look like it.  Documentation for [xmlDocPtr](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html#xmlDoc) says that `name` is "name/filename/URI of the document", but this isn't getting populated in my tests with `xmlReadFile`.

Looking through the code, it looks like the filename isn't saved in the doc, and the parser context disappears at the end of parser.c's `xmlDoRead()`.

Comment: I'm afraid that you are right (that's what I found too), but I want to hold out a bit in the vain hope that someone else knows something we don't.

Comment: Nothing else was forthcoming, so I'm afraid this is the answer.